# Run a MySql stored procedure Script Against MySQL using Powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell, azure-devops

I want to execute a MySQL stored procedure on a MySQL 5.6 server that is a QA environment. This is part of a Continuous Delivery implementation via Azure piplines.

For example: My `.sql` file has multiple stored procedures which are executed successfully by MySQL Workbench, but the same file I want to execute via PowerShell.

**.sql content:**

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `test`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `test` ()
BEGIN
select * from organisations;
END 
//

DELIMITER ;

DROP procedure IF EXISTS `test1`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `test1` ()
BEGIN
select * from organisations;
END 
//

DELIMITER ;
```

**PowerShell script code:**

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")

[string]$sMySQLUserName = 'xxx'
[string]$sMySQLPW = 'xxx'
[string]$sMySQLDB = 'xxx'
[string]$sMySQLHost = 'localhost'
[string]$sConnectionString = "server="+$sMySQLHost+";port=3306;uid=" + $sMySQLUserName + ";pwd=" + $sMySQLPW + ";database="+$sMySQLDB 

$oConnection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection($sConnectionString)
$Error.Clear()
try
{
    $oConnection.Open()
    write-host "Connection opened"
}
catch
{
    write-warning ("Could not open a connection to Database $sMySQLDB on Host $sMySQLHost. Error: "+$Error[0].ToString())
}

#$oTransAction=$oConnection.BeginTransaction()
$oMYSQLCommand = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$oMYSQLCommand.Connection=$oConnection
#$oMYSQLCommand.Transaction=$oMYSQLTransaction
#$sql = Get-Content D:\Release\ConsoleDev\SqlScript\testprocedure.sql
$sql = [io.file]::ReadAllText('D:\Release\ConsoleDev\SqlScript\testprocedure - Copy.sql')
$oMYSQLCommand.CommandText = $sql
write-host $sql
try
{
$iRowsAffected=$oMYSQLCommand.executeNonQuery()

 }
 catch
{
    write-warning ("ERROR occured while ExecuteNonQuery")

}
# Do some Inserts or updates here and commit your changes

finally
{

$oConnection.Close()
write-host "Closing Connection"
}
```

PowerShell throws the following error:

> WARNING: ERROR occurred while ExecuteNonQuery

I think the problem in executing DELIMITER //.

Comment: Currently, you're hiding the true error output with your try..catch. Add `Write-Error $_` into your catch block to see what the actual error is.

Comment: Thanks Mark, i have added write-Error $_ the error in out put is Error running MySQL command: 
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "You have an error in your 
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `test` ()
BEGIN
select * from organisations;
END$' at line 1"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,DevVM- 
   107-MySql.ps1

Comment: I have resolved the issues with below changes -  1)$oMYSQLCommand = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlScript 2) $oMYSQLCommand.Query  = $sql 3) $oMYSQLCommand.Execute() and finally it has been executed and stored proc in my DB.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issues with below changes - 1)$oMYSQLCommand = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlScript 2) $oMYSQLCommand.Query = $sql 3) $oMYSQLCommand.Execute() and finally it has been executed and stored proc in my DB. –